# Ребятки накидайте мне задач для начинающих по js

Tags: javascript

Если есть интересные сайты с задачками , кроме кодвар.

Comment: Заметил, что минусы вопросу ставят, а почему - никто не отвечает. Да, вопрос не соответствует правилам сообщества, но почему никто не укажет это? А теперь вопрос к автору - а вы пытались гуглить? Банально, 1 сайт из запроса "javascript задачи" - https://tproger.ru/problems/javascript-exercises-for-beginners-geekbrains/. Или, например, найти алгоритм какой-либо задачи и перевести его на нужный (в вашем случае, javascript). Вариантов масса. Возвращаясь к оформлению вопроса, не думаете ли, что в заголовке вопроса стоит указывать более точную проблему? А в теле вопроса - хотя-бы "Привет" писать

Comment: Экономия времени. В гугле вариантов множество , хотелось увидеть , что большинство делает.

Comment: А время участников форума вы не бережёте? Оформите корректно вопрос как минимум. Лично мне неприятно отвечать даже на подобные. Вам ведь люди отвечают чисто из-за стремления помочь новичкам, разобрать проблемный код/вопрос

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript
вот к примеру

Comment: Frehzy то что ты здесь возмущаешься уже говорит о том , что времени у тебя вагон. Я не поверю , что другими управляет желание помочь. Для опытных это просто развлекуха.

Comment: @Frehzy "хотя-бы "Привет" писать" --- кому  и зачем?  https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/93/191482

Comment: вот и я об этом подумал)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Если это единственное, что вас смущает в моих сообщениях - хорошо. Возможно, я просто зажрался и с вопросом всё нормально, и мои "выступления" совершенно бессмысленны. Не вижу смысла продолжать дальше это разведение флуда

Comment: @Frehzy с вопросом не все нормально, вопросу 1 голос до закрытия остался. никто просто не тратит время на бесполезные комментарии о качестве вопроса. Все будет указано в причине закрытия

Comment: @VDVchannel опытные сидят на SO и для развлекухи решают задачи которые подкидывают неопытные. Решать задачи еще на каких-то ресурсах незачем, так что опытные вам других ресурсов не накидают тут.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Вот задача для начинающих: нужно создать приложение, выводящее такое стихотворение:

**Из-за леса, из-за гор**

**Показался** [некая переменная **a**].

**И такая дребедень**

**Появлялась каждый день**.

Переменная может принимать такие значения: **прокурор, пахтакор, дед Егор, матадор, светофор, симофор, мародёр, ухожор, мухомор**. После каждого обновления страницы в стихотворение должно случайным образом подставляться одно из этих значений.

А вот ещё одна задача для средних JavaScript-еров: нарисовать синусоиду не используя **Math.sin()** и **Math.cos()**. Успеха!

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136537/discussion-on-answer-by---------js).